# Gern geschehen - you are welcome

Tags: english-to-german

I know that the translation for the expression *you are welcome* is *gern geschehen.*

But the literal translation should be *du bist willkommen*. Is there any way to rationalize this translation? Has the expression *you are welcome* any historical reason to exist?

Comment: You seem to be asking about the English expression, which would be off-topic here. If not, please clarify.

Comment: @CarstenS Ist das nicht nur eine Frage des Standpunkts? Für einen deutsch Sprechenden ist die Frage warum "gern geschehen" mit "you are welcome" übersetzt wird - das wäre in der Tat eine Frage für die englische SE-site. Für einen englisch Sprechenden, der nur "you are welcome" kennt, ist hingegen die interessante Frage, warum das im Deutschen mit "gern geschehen" "übersetzt" wird.

Comment: You should not think that much about "translations". You should think about use-cases: What do people who are familiar with a language say in certain situations. The proper wording is irrelevant. In situations here intended, proficient users of German say "Gern geschehen", or (old-fashioned) "Keine Ursache", and other phrases. The proper wording in other languages is not relevant. - In Bulgarian you would say "заповядей", litterally "Give an order!". Still you would not say "give an order" in English.

Comment: @IQV, das gilt vielleicht für den Teil "Is there any way to rationalize this translation?", den ich ohnehin nicht verstehe. Der Teil "Has the expression you are welcome any historical reason to exist?" scheint mir klar eine Frage zur englischen Sprache zu sein.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Gern geschehen* is not a translation of *you are welcome* in a strict sense. It's what you usually say if you want to reply to a Danke/Thank you. It is not so much a statement but a social convention so a literal translation does not make much sense.

By the way, there are also other possibilities in German, for example "Keine Ursache" or "Bitte (schön)".

As for why English uses "you are welcome", I don't know the answer, and this question would be off-topic here anyway.

Comment: There is an English alternative to "you're welcome", it says "not at all" which is quite close in meaning to the "keine Ursache" RHa has mentioned